# How do I reuse processes in a parallel program in C

Tags: c, parallel-processing

I am computing a matrix mult of 200 by 200 dimensions. I can use maximum 8 processes . I am forking child processes to compute rows. Either I can make one process do 4 rows and run them in parallel or I can make one row per process, ie 5 rows being dealt in parallel at a time followed by another 5 by reusing same processes. Which would be more efficient?

Comment: 20x20 matrix multiplication is tiny.  Multiple processes do not sound like the right approach here.

Comment: How many cores do you have? If there's no I/O or cross-communication, that should answer your question. Also, if it's just numbers in your matrix, forking will take much longer than the multiply.

Comment: That was just for example , let it be 200*200 .. , i have 5 cores and I have modified the q a bit

Comment: Ok, well you should still consider threads, instead of processes, as it avoids having to set up shared memory or IPC.

Comment: I know but I have to do using processes only and ya I am using shared memory for IPC

Comment: Are you only computing **one** matrix multiplication?  If so, then multiple processes are still a waste of effort; the processing will be done in a few milliseconds (even for 200x200), so will probably be dominated by setup time.  The real problem here is to figure out a cache-efficient memory-access pattern (but that's a [solved problem](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=matrix+multiply+cache)).

Comment: 5 cores? What processor do you have? I have never heard of a 5-core processor...

Answer (score 2):

Since in this case all the jobs take the same effort (they have the same number of multiplications and additions) it would make more sense to go for the first option (4 rows per process). The second option (1 row per process each time) makes more sense when the jobs are heterogeneous in the time they take to complete or you need low latency. You can consider the overheads for each option.

In the first option the overhead consist of:

- Dividing the work.
- Launching the processes.
- Gathering the results.

In the second option the overhead is:

- Dividing the work.
- Launching the processes.
- When a worker is done, ask for another piece.
- Receive another piece.
- Gather results.

You can see that in the second option there is more overhead.

As for a possible architecture for the second option you could use a server-client architecture, one process will act as server and the rest as clients. A server would be in charge of dividing the work, giving it to clients when asked for it and gathering the results. You could either gather the results after each job is completed or at the end. At the beginning the server will create the clients, give each of them a job and then wait until asked for more work. When a client is finished with the work it was given it will ask the server for another job and give the server the results it has computed. This will be repeated until the server has no more work to give, at which point it will inform the clients of it so they can exit.